# Start chapter on left hand side with page number 1

Tags: numbering, chapters, double-sided, scrbook

## Context

For my bachelor thesis I want my chapters and appendix content to open on the left of my scrbook document, which I already achieved with the current setup. As you can see in the MWE document, the chapters open on the left hand side of the document, but get numbered as the second page of that part, respectively: page 2 and B.

## Request

If I put a `\clearpage` before changing the numbering the page number is correct but the two side style is switched and wrong from there on. I would like to have those numbered as the first page 1 and A. How can I achieve this?

## MWE

https://www.overleaf.com/12454989rnwmtvhnjtpz#/47421405/
or

```
\documentclass[a4paper
               , 12pt
               , toc=listof
               , titlepage
               , toc=bibliography
               , open=right
               , ngerman
]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[sfdefault,lf]{carlito}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\renewcommand*\oldstylenums[1]{\carlitoOsF #1}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[a4paper,
            inner=3.5cm,
            outer=2.5cm,
            includeheadfoot,
            top=2cm,
            bottom=2cm,
            footskip=1cm,
            ]{geometry}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\begin{titlepage}
\Huge
Some title page text
\end{titlepage}
\normalsize
\clearpage

\KOMAoptions{open=left}

\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspacing

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\Blinddocument

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}

\chapter{Some appendix chapter}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks strange to me. Maybe you found a special feature ;). However, you can try this little workaround. After the toc and `\onehalfspacing`, instead of only `\cleardoubleoddpage`, put the following: `\KOMAoptions{open=right}
 
 \cleardoubleoddpage\thispagestyle{empty}\null
 \newpage`. From then on, you should only invoke `\cleardoublepage` before a chapter (without `odd`).

Comment: A left hand page has an even number by definition.

Comment: @Johannes_B I get that even pages are even "print-wise", that does not hinder me from counting them as odd pages. Consider it as a different label

Comment: @nox the numbering from 1 and the position on the left works fine. Yet, the same problem as I had persists anyhow. The left hand side pages are then styled as odd pages - meaning the inner and outer spacings are wrong and the page number is on the wrong side of the page...

Comment: I see, what about defining a new counter `\newcounter{mypage}` and then redefining the page number printed by using `\renewcommand{\thepage}{\setcounter{mypage}{\value{page}}\addtocounter{mypage}{-1}\themypage}`? This doesn't work well with `hyperref` though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research and experimenting I came up with a solution that works for me at least. It works with the part environment as an "odd page starter". This lets the following chapters start on even pages without the strange page numbering effects.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\preto\part{\KOMAoptions{open=right}}
\preto\addpart{\KOMAoptions{open=right}}
\renewcommand*\partheademptypage{\KOMAoptions{open=left}}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\title{test}
\author{test}
\maketitle
\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\onehalfspacing
\KOMAoptions{open=right}

\mainmatter
\part{Part 1 on the right}
\KOMAoptions{open=left}
\addchap{Chapter 1 on the left}
\lipsum[1-4]
\chapter{Chapter 2 on the left}
\lipsum[1-5]

\cleardoubleoddpage
\pagenumbering{Alph}
\backmatter
\part{Appendix on the right}
\chapter{Chapter 3 on the left}
\lipsum[1-5]
\chapter{Chapter 4 on the left}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```